# What's the best way to set boolean value in multiple reactive objects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a large component, with lots of `boolean` reactive `states` and each DOM element has to change 4-5 of them whenever a button is clicked. MWE:

```
<button @click="state.val1 = false; state.val2 = false; state.val3 = false">click me</div>

<p>{{state.val1}}</p>
<p>{{state.val2}}</p>
<p>{{state.val3}}</p>
```

`button` is an example of such DOM elements and it gets confusing quickly so I was wondering if there is a better, cleaner way of doing that.

I've tried:

```
<button @click="state.val1, state.val2 = false">
```

and

```
<button @click="state['val1', 'val2'] = false">
```

both of which only change the second object `val2`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to write a generic method:

```js
const myObj = {
    state: {
        key1: false,
        key2: true,
        key3: false
    }
};

function changeState(name, keys, newVal) {
    Object.keys(this[name]).forEach(key => {
        if (keys.includes(key)) {
            this[name][key] = newVal;
        }
    })
}

changeState.call(myObj, 'state', ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], false);

console.log(myObj);

changeState.call(myObj, 'state', ['key1', 'key3'], true);

console.log(myObj);
```

So in Vue, you'd get something like:

```
<button @click="changeState('state', ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], false)">
```